# Add logs in xCode console with ASL

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, logging

I have implemented logging functionality with ASL. And I can see logging in the Console application in MAC OS. Is there any way by which I can see console logs produced by ASL Logger redirected in Xcode Console?

I have opened ask by below statement.

```
asl_open(NULL, "com.apple.console", 0);
```

which is logging in apple's console. can I change in above statement and get the logging in Xcode's console.